# Pandas plot 22 series in 11 plots in 1 Figure

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I can plot 11 Series in 11 Graphs and in 1 Figure:

```
NG = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
serieslist = []

for n in NG:
    l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    df = pd.DataFrame(l)
    serieslist.append(df)

df = pd.concat(serieslist, axis = 1)
df.plot(grid = 1, subplots = True, layout = (6,2), sharey = True)
```

[image]

How do I plot 22 series (of which 2 shall always be in one plot) in 1 Figure? So that means 22 plots in 11 Graphs. The code below only gives 22 graphs:

```
NG = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
serieslist = []

for n in NG:
    l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    df = pd.DataFrame(l)
    serieslist.append(df)
    serieslist.append(df)


df = pd.concat(serieslist, axis = 1)
df.plot(grid = 1, subplots = True, layout = (12,2), sharey = True)
```

[image]

Edit:
This is not 100% the solution I want but it looks a bit prettier:

```
import pandas as pd

NG = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
dflist1 = []
dflist2 = []

l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [6,5,4,3,2,1]


for n in NG:
    df = pd.DataFrame(l)
    dflist1.append(df)
    df = pd.concat(dflist1, axis = 1)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
    dflist2.append(df2)
    df2 = pd.concat(dflist2, axis = 1)

df.plot(grid = 1, subplots = True, layout = (12,1), sharey = True)
df2.plot(grid = 1, subplots = True, layout = (12,1), sharey = True)
```

Output: 2 figure. Now how to combine the plots into 1 figure?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use for this [`matplotlib.pyplot.subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html).

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

In a single cell:

- iterate over the values `i in range(11)`
- In iteration *i*

  - Call `plt.subplot(6, 2, i + 1)`
  - Plot the DataFrame consisting of inputs `i` and `i +`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not understand the last Point. How do I do that? With your solution I do not have any dataframe, do I?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov In my suggestion you would move `df = pd.concat(serieslist, axis = 1)` *into* the loop, creating a DataFrame of two columns, and plot it within the iteration. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: putting this code snippet into the loop didnt change anything. I did a little change to the code, see above. Maybe you can give me another hint?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov Can you post as an edit to the question (or a new question) the current code? If so, ping here, and I"ll gladly look at it.

Comment: To isolate my problem: I want to plot 1 subplot with 2 data series. But Pandas is plotting every data series into a new subplot, if the subplot affix is activated. How can I make 1 subplot with a Dataframe with 2 data series?